# Problems with my technique in making a Belgian Liege Waffle

Tags: baking, dough, waffle

I have been following a very nice recipe to the dot. However, I encounter some problems. My final texture is more similar to a bread than a waffle.

Is this because I use trimoline instead of honey? Some recipe use baking powder / diet sprite, what is this for?

Also, could I freeze the dough after I mix it with the pearl sugar? How long could the mix dough stay in the freezer?

Comment: I don't see the problem, Liege waffles are supposed to have a bread like texture. Anything with baking powder is not real Liege style.

Comment: Normally, I think you should use fresh yeast, but I've seen recipes with baking powder. Could you give us more details (the whole recipe or pictures)?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your Liege waffle has breadlike texture is that it is supposed to have a breadlike texture.

While currently in America, waffles tend to have a uniform texture with small variations, and everybody has come to expect waffles within this range, in Europe waffles are any dough or batter baked in a waffle iron. I have waffle books which contain waffles made from batter, cookie-dough-style dough, bread-dough-style dough, and others. They are all baked in a waffle iron, but their final texture ends up being similar to bread, cookies, etc., becasue this is how dough works.

Traditional Liege waffles are a type of waffles made from firm yeast dough, like bread. And the texture is more similar to bread than to a standard American waffle. You didn't do anything wrong, you got the result intended by the recipe author.

If you don't like this type of waffle, you should search for a different recipe.

Answer (score -1):

Sift flour baking powder and salt, seperate eggs, beat yolks add heavy cream, keep beating, stir in flour combo until smooth. in seperate bowl beat egg whites until stiff, fold into batter, refrigerate for half an hour. pour into preheated waffle iron serve with butter and honey.  mmmm yummmm, thats just me though